# Проблема с перезагрузкой оператора

Tags: c++, очередь

Пишу очередь с приоритетом. Необходимо перегрузить оператор +, но наталкиваюсь на ошибку: "Вызвано исключение: нарушение доступа для чтения.
helpPtr было 0xCCCCCCCC.". 
Падает в функции `void push(T val, size_t prt)` на строке `while (helpPtr && helpPtr->priority < prt)` во время исполнения.
Вот реализация

```
friend const queue operator + (const queue& q1, const queue& q2)
{
    queue newQ(q1);
    Node* helpPtr(q2.tail);
    while (helpPtr) {
        newQ.push(helpPtr->value, helpPtr->priority);
        helpPtr = helpPtr->prev;
    }
    return queue(newQ);
}
```

[Здесь](https://pastebin.com/CKZFJ4iu) код.

Comment: перегрузить. "Перегрузка операторов". :)

Comment: Не заменил, в `struct Node{ int value; //T value; ... }`, но к ошибке отношения не имеет.

Comment: @7px, не заметил, исправил, спасибо.

Comment: "но наталкиваюсь на ошибку". На *какую* ошибку? В какой строке? Почему в вопросе отсутствует эта информация?

Comment: Ваш код некомпилируем в принципе из-за грубого игнорирования правил констатной корректности. Ваш конструктор копирования бесполезен из-за того, что принимает *неконстантную* ссылку. Пока вы не расставите по коду спецификатор `const` везде, где он нужен, никаких шансов не будет. То есть править надо все.

Comment: А что это такое? `head = tail = nullptr;`

Comment: @AnT, спасибо. Вроде бы исправил. Но, к ошибке это отношение не имело.

Comment: @ИванПоднебесный Опишите ошибку. Вы писали, что в функции push "падает". Т.е. во время исполнения? Отредактируете вопрос, внеся более подробную информацию об ошибке.

Comment: @AnT Вы правы насчет бесполезности конструктора, принимающего неконстантную ссылку. Но тем не менее, такой конструктор может быть скомпилирован (GCC, как минимум), если не будет копирования из временных объектов.

Comment: @7px, да, падает во время исполнения программы.

Comment: @7px: К компилируемости конструктора претензий нет. Но возврат из функций по значению может предполагать именно копирование временных объектов, пока мы не завязываемся на гарантированное исключение копий в С++17.

Comment: @ИванПоднебесный В строке деструкторе у вас вечный цикл при не нулевом числе элементов. Полагаю, строка 34 должна выглядеть так: Node* buf(helpPtr->next);

Answer (score 1):

Конструктор копирования никак не инициализирует поля `head` и `tail` нового объекта и начинает делать `push`, в то время как в этих полях содержится мусор. В результате все падает.